# Notepad++ - Remove everything except URLs

Tags: filter, notepad++

I have a textdocument with many URLs in it. The URls have many different endings like, .net, .com, .de and so on ... All the URLs have NO http:// oder www. infront. There is many other text in the document, it looks something like this:

```
"First you go to test.de and then you can go to test2.com. After that you should ..."
```

I want to filter in Notepad++ now so that i have only the URLs with a linebrak like this:

```
test.de
test2.com
```

Can anyone tell me how i could realize that?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++, You could record a macro to do this with a regex:

**Note**: Make a copy of the file before you start, just in case.

- Insert Some Unique chars at the start, and at the end of the text file, something like `STARTSTARTSTART` and `ENDENDEND`.  Alpha only, no special chars
- You going to need the proper regex, something like `\w([a-zA-Z0-9\.]{2,6})\.([a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,6})`  that matches the sample you gave, but there is probably a better one.  Make sure that the `Search Mode` on the `Find` dialog has `(*) Regular Expression` Selected
- Start the macro recording.  `Macro > Start Recording`
- Search for `STARTSTARTSTART` and click `Find Next`
- Search for `\w([a-zA-Z0-9\.]{2,6})\.([a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,6})` and click `find Next` and then click `close` and then `Cut` the found term
- Search for `ENDENDEND` and click `find next` and then click `close` and press `Enter` and then `Paste`
- End the Macro recording `Macro > Stop Recording`
- Play the Macro with `Macro > Playback`

That should get you started....